# Add lines above and below title

Tags: titles

Currently working on a document of type article. I'd like to add two horizontal lines above and below the title. I tried the following:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}

     \line(1,0){250}
     \title{A Title}
     \line(1,0){250}

     \author{FirstName LastName}
     \maketitle

    \clearpage
    \end{document}
```

This does not give the desired effect, and splits the title page into multiple pages. Could you advise?

Comment: @Johannes_B My question was posted in 2014, whereas the indicated question posted in 2016. I guess it makes sense to mark that question as duplicate???

Comment: We often close older questions as duplicates of newer questions.

Comment: @Johannes_B Why mark a question with a good answer as duplicate of a very generic one which does not show how to add lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the line inside `\title`s argument:

```
\title{\line(1,0){250}\\A Title\\\line(1,0){250}}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


 \title{\line(1,0){250}\\A Title\\\line(1,0){250}}

 \author{FirstName LastName}
 \maketitle

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Same with `titling` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\begin{document}
\pretitle{%
\begin{center}\LARGE
\rule{3in}{0.4pt}\par
}
\posttitle{\par\rule{3in}{0.4pt}\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}

 \title{A Title}

 \author{FirstName LastName}
 \maketitle

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well you can custom easily  your title page with the `titlepage` environment. Belong your MWE we can get:

[image: Titlepage environment result]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\begin{flushright}
\Huge A Title \\[14pt]
First Name Last Name
\end{flushright}
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}
\vspace*{\stretch{2}}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Notice the way of build the lines and their thickness.

You don't need more. You can build manually a title page with this environment. If you do that will be useful to use commands such as `\vspace`, `\vspace*`, `\vfill`, between others.