# How can I add thickness to a line?

Tags: titles

I have this title with two lines surrounding it.

```
 \title{\line(1,0){350}\\Whatever\\\line(1,0){350}}
```

I want to adjust thickness to these lines and I tried playing with numbers in the parentheses but that didn't change anything.
Thanks for your support in advance.

Here is the complete code for this article

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\title{\line(1,0){350}\\Whatever\\\line(1,0){350}}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet concecteture... 
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a minimal; but complete code, illustrating your problem?

Comment: Your answer is similar to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197278/add-lines-above-and-below-title. Use `titling` package and put into the dots (for example 5pt) of the command `\rule{3in}{....}` to increase the thickness.

Comment: @Bernard I've added a few lines of code. Hope it helps.